# Configuring the compile path of sbt-less plugin

Tags: playframework, less, sbt, playframework-2.3

I'm using play framework with this plugin. I have the following structure for `public` folder;

```
├───app
│   ├───css
│   ├───img
│   ├───js
│   │   ├───apis
│   │   ├───config
│   │   ├───controllers
│   │   ├───directives
│   │   ├───filters
│   │   ├───locale
│   │   └───services
│   └───views
└───test
```

In `build.sbt`, I have the following;

```
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"

excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"

LessKeys.rootpath in Assets := "public/app/css"
```

In my `main.scala.html`, I have the following link tag;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='@routes.Assets.at("app/css/main.css")'>
```

And lastly, my `routes` has the following;

```
GET      /assets/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

However, less configuration in build.sbt doesn't seem to work. I want to compile public/app/css/main.less. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Play documentation:

> Compilable assets in Play must be defined in the `app/assets` directory.

And the sbt-less readme:

> Set rootpath for url rewriting in relative imports and urls.

It seems like there is no way to do this, as Play needs a place where it can expect compilable assets and not Scala/Java code. The `rootpath` key appears to just be for re-writing imports/urls in LESS files.

What you need is:

```
├───app
│   ├───assets
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───img
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───apis
│   │       ├───config
│   │       ├───controllers
│   │       ├───directives
│   │       ├───filters
│   │       ├───locale
│   │       └───services
│   └───views
└───test
```

Answer (score 0):

The default path to assets defined in the SbtWeb plugin is: `app/assets`:

`sourceDirectory in Assets := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "assets"`

so it can easily be overridden:

`sourceDirectory in Assets := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "path" / "to" / "assets"`